# Encode NSArray before save

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdata

I have a string with accent **é** within my database, when I take this string of there and saved it in a `NSArray` instead of he save the string **é** it saves **'\U00e9'**.

If I put this string in a UITextField, the system places the string with accent. But this code has a problem! I need to send this string to another device (using a framework) and for that I do as follows:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];
data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];//The array contain the string in database

NSArray *arrayReceived = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Inside `NSArray` have the string **\U00e9**, but I need to save this string inside my database for this I must find some way to convert the string **'\U00e9'** to the string **é** before saving to the database again! How to do it?

Comment: How are you seeing the `\u00e9`?  You need to understand that it could just be that *view* of the character that is presenting this unicode-escaped version, when in fact the character is perfectly properly encoded within the string (using UTF-8, for example).  It doesn't look to me like anything is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have a problem. Your `é` and `\u00e9` are the same thing, you can just think of them as being described in different ways.

See [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm) for a description of the unicode for `é`.

Assuming that the framework / system that you send the encoded array to uses it in a sensible way (i.e. considering the unicode content) then you will be fine. The fact that you are using `NSKeyedArchiver` to encode an `NSArray` indicates that this is indeed the case.

Basically, just be aware that `NSLog` and UI display are vert different things. `NSLog` gives you a very raw view of data whereas UI gives you a human modified view of the data.